# Bootstrap collapse panel in reactjs render method

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I want to collapse few columns in the ReactJS table row. Please find the code that am trying.

```
render() {
    return (
            <tr>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" 
            data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#collapseExample" 
            aria-expanded="false" 
            aria-controls="collapseExample">
            +
            </button>
            <td>{ this.state.item.line_number }</td>
            <td>{ this.state.item.product_code }</td>
            </tr>

            <tr className="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div className="well">
            <td>{ this.state.item.net_price }</td>
            <td>{ this.state.item.discount }</td>
            </div>
           </tr>
          )
        }
```

I want to open the panel (collapse panel) once i clicked on the "+" button. But am getting error on the 2nd  tag. Am not able to render two  tag in render() method.

How i can achieve this solution.?

Comment: There are at least two issues with your code, one being that TR elements can only have child TD's or TH's (you have a button), and on that button you're using "class" instead of className

Comment: className is fine., that is typo error. but not sure about how to render another <tr> and that should be collapse one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am using ReactJS 15.6.1 version and in this version `return()` method wont support multiple `<tr>` tags to render. From ReactJS 16+ version we can able to `return()` array of components. So, its possible with ReactJS 16+ version.